# Apply filter to a specific area of a Bitmap - Android

Tags: android, bitmap

I have a color bitmap which is filtered to grayscale. 
When a user touches it I want to animate an expanding circle of coloration from the touch point.
I would prefer not to use two bitmaps (one color and one grayscale) and a mask to get this effect.
I can work out the animation.
Can you apply a paint filter to a particular (circular) area of a bitmap?
Not sure if it is relevant but the Bitmap is displayed in a SurfaceView.